# Can't get access to the Events in Visual Studio Community Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to migrate my old Visual Studio extension to the new 2022 Studio. Found some fancy solution named 'Community Visual Studio Toolkit', but got some issues. When I use the `ProvideAutoLoad` attribute for loading my extension when a user opens some solution, I can't get access to the `WindowEvents` which I need to sign my event handlers. This is the error on debugging: https://snipboard.io/yUXIed.jpg

So this is the code I use, and here I have the error:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
public sealed class MyPackage : ToolkitPackage
{
    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        await this.RegisterCommandsAsync();
        VS.Events.WindowEvents.ActiveFrameChanged += WindowEvents_ActiveFrameChanged;       
    }
}
```

And the thing is my old implementation works with this code:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
public sealed class MyPackage : ToolkitPackage
{
    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        await this.RegisterCommandsAsync();
        // Getting `DTE2 dte` trough standard way...
        dte.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += WindowEvents_WindowActivated;
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use old kinds of code in the new extension version, so, how to fix this issue in first example of implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure about the "perfection" of this solution, but with this line of code added before access to the events - it works.

`await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);`

Seems like you have to be in main thread to access these events.